# C++: When I input a string, the program for some reason expects more and causes problems for the entire code

Tags: c++

I am having problems of inputting on this code.
I am calling a switch statement where I add input into a vector.

```
case 'a':
        {
            cout <<"Enter the item name:" << endl;
            getline(cin, itemName);
            cin.ignore();

            cout <<"Enter the item description:" << endl;
            getline(cin, itemDescription);
            cin.ignore();


            cout <<"Enter the item price:" << endl;
            cin >> price;

            cout <<"Enter the item quantity:" << endl;
            cin >> quantity;

            ItemToPurchase item1;

            item1.SetName(itemName);
            item1.SetDescription(itemDescription);
            item1.SetPrice(price);
            item1.SetQuantity(quantity);

            cart.AddItem(item1);
        }

        break;
```

Whats happening here is that when I try to input name or descrption, it has a problem where when I hit enter after I input my string, it expects another input before moving on. same for description.
Then, the bigger issue, if I call that function again and try to use this switch, when I hit enter after inputting my desciption, my program falls into an infinite loop. I can't figure out whats causing this.

Here are other code if they are nessasry by the way.

Here is the begining of the code

```
void PrintMenu(ShoppingCart &cart)
{
    char options;

    string itemName;
    string itemDescription;
    int price;
    int quantity;

    while (options != 'q')
    {
        cout << "MENU" << endl;
        cout << "a - Add item to cart" << endl;
        cout << "d - Remove item from cart" << endl;
        cout << "c - Change item quantity" << endl;
        cout << "i - Output items' description" << endl;
        cout << "o - Output shopping cart" << endl;
        cout << "q - Quit" << endl;
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Choose an option:" << endl;
        cin >> options;
        cin.ignore();


        switch(options)
    {//This is where the above case is}
```

And this is the code for my addItem function:

```
void ShoppingCart::AddItem(ItemToPurchase item)
{
    cartItems.push_back(item);

    return;
}
```

Cart items is a vector of a class, if i haven't mentioned yet that by the way.

Also, I cant change what I pass because the directions tell me specifically, "adds an item to cart item vector. has parameter ItemToPurchase, doesn't return anything."

please help. I have looked through my code to try to find the issue and nothing.

Comment: Well, what do you expect when you randomly spray calls to `std::istream::ignore()`, without a clear understand of what it does, and if it's needed (it's not)? `ignore()` is never needed when using plain calls to `std::getline()` to read lines of text, as input. Piling on more confusion is the mixing of formatted input extraction operatiors, `>>` with `std::getline()`. That is a recipe of fragile, error prone, input handling. Either use `std::getline()` to parse input, and nothing else, or use `>>`, and nothing else. Mixing the two together is possible, but difficult, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. The problem seems to be that I need to put cin.ignore(); **BEFORE**, input. When I did that, that fixed my issues.